# Xcode gave strange newsstand-error when trying to submit an app

Tags: ios, xcode, newsstand-kit

finaly everything works fine and I want to submit my first app the the Appstore. But when I click submit in Xcode 4.1 I get this strange error message:

> To include newsstand features, the info.plist must include the uinewsstandapp=true.

(Exact the same and Google doesn't know anything).

But I don't use newsstand and i don't want to use. Where is my mistake?

Markus

Xcode Version 4.1

Comment: Try going to your info.plist file: add new row and type `uinewsstandapp` for the key. Set it's type to Boolean, and its value to yes. and if there is a `uinewsstandapp` already in one of the keys make sure that the value is YES.

Comment: when i do it, xcode wants that i  activate newsstand for my app in itunes connect. but this is no newsstand app and i don't want to use it:(

Answer (score 168):

The new version of Xcode introduced a `NewsstandIcon` under `CFBundleIcon`. Delete it.

Comment: Thanks a lot. For people don't know CFBoundleIcon, it's a key in info.plist file

Comment: perfect..  that was an unneeded headache IMHO.  Go Xcode team!

Comment: Do the Xcode developers ever actually use their own software??

Answer (score 107):

For those having trouble finding it:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Wonderful +1 for this illustration!

Comment: if i delete Newstand Icon,  is there any effect to our project?

Comment: @Babul Not that I know of.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to make sure that the UINewsstandApp setting is not present in the Info.plist

Answer (score 0):

you can remove this from info.plist Newsstand Icon Or You Can set this key equal true : UINewsstandApp = true Info.plist key.