# Xcode 4 Deploying Apps to AppStore

Tags: iphone, xcode, profile, provisioning, keychain

Does anyone know where I can find a complete step-by-step guide for deploying an iPhone app from development tot he app store.  I have actually done it before but with the new version of Xcode it is proving difficult.

My ,main problem is with the "Archive".  When I validate, I get a lengthy error message.  I know it has something to do with my provisioning profile and my keychain, etc.  I would like to start over if I can.  Apple documentation has never been good at giving you a detailed explanation.  Any direction would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7924085/how-to-submit-an-ios-app-without-xcode

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the link you can follow... a step by step Guide... Hope it helps to you.

http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-programming-tutorials/submitting-iphone-apps-to-the-apple-app-store-a-step-by-step-guide/

Comment: :) Great... if you like you can vote up also the answer... it will increase your points also.

Answer (score 4):

I am inclined to reference apple in spite of your statement

> Apple documentation has never been good at giving you a detailed
>   explanation.

[Provisioning Portal - Distribution](https://developer.apple.com/ios/manage/distribution/index.action)

You can start at the top and work your way down.

- Obtaining your iOS Distribution Certificate
- Create and download your iOS Distribution Provisioning Profile for App Store Distribution
- Creating and Downloading a Distribution Provisioning Profile for Ad Hoc Distribution
- Building your Application with Xcode for Distribution
- Verifying a Successful Distribution Build
- Updating your Application

Sorry if you have actually followed all the steps outlined there and are still having problems.

Comment: cool edit.  How did you bullet point my list?? with 6 characters.  Note: I mostly develop ios, android and backend of websites, so I am not sure what tag you used.