# How do I send a built project to someone else so that they may submit it to the App Store on their developer account?

Tags: xcode, app-store

I'm building an app for someone who wants to submit the app to the iOS app store on their own developer account, instead of mine. I'd rather not send my source code, so how might I send them a built project that they can open in XCode to submit for review, without revealing the source code?

Comment: *What they want to review in the code??* Ask you client for provisioning profiles for that app created using his developer account. Tell him to share them with you & code sign the project with those provisioning profiles. Dont forget to tell them to create **Distribution Provisioning Profile**. Archive the project to create .ipa file & then send .ipa file via email. He can use this file to upload to app store

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None of the build project can be opened in XCode.

XCode is an IDE for writing, editing source code, not just to launch and submit for review.

You need to give source Code, if you want the person to use XCode.

EDIT:

[Submit Project without using XCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7924085/how-to-submit-an-ios-app-without-xcode).

Comment: Is it possible to upload a build project for review without using XCode?