# Signing iOS application the command line way goes wrong

Tags: ios, xcode, code-signing

I need your help for some problem with the signature of my iOS application :

- When I do it by "Product > Archive > Distribute" all is fine, my ipa is created and installation via iTunes works perfectly. (the ipa file weight 630Ko)
- So I try to do it by command line and I encountered several problems (I tried this tutorials : [here](http://bdunagan.com/2011/12/11/ad-hoc-and-app-store-ipas-with-xcrun/), [here](http://stoneofarc.wordpress.com/2012/12/11/automatically-build-archive-and-distribute-to-testflight/), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7924085/how-to-submit-an-ios-app-without-xcode) and [here](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?159924-Adhoc-builds-do-not-work)) :

1 - My path to the ".app" folder  is really long and could be false because when I choose "show in finder" in Xcode it shows me "Debug-iphoneos" folder instead of "Release-iphoneos" folder.

2 - The .ipa file is smaller (550-557Ko according to the tutorial).

3 - When I install it throught iTunes, the icon stay dark and when I click on it the text change to "installation..." and nothing more happens.

Did someone ever ran into this situation and found a miracle solution ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use this GEM to generate builds by the terminal: https://github.com/nomad/shenzhen

It handles most of the pain for you, but the problem your are reporting should be related with the provision profile. Check if the uuid of the device is in the provision profile and if the provision profile stills valid.