# Xcode keeps giving me Newsstand error everytime I try Validate my app through Archive

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

Every time I try to validate my application in Xcode through Organizer - Archives I keep bumping in to errors:

"The Info.plist specifies that this is a Newsstand app. In iTunes Connect, you must also enable Newsstand for your app version."

"In the CFBundleIcons.UINewsstandIcon dictionary, make sure that your
Newsstand app includes an array of CFBundleIcons.UINewsstandIcon dictionary, Do not include the UIPerenderIcon key in the CFBundleIcons.UINewsstandIcon dictionary."

"Your Newsstand app must specify a valid UINewsstandBindingType in the CFBundleIcons.UINewsstandIcon dictionary."

I began getting these errors after I followed this guide:
[Xcode gave strange newsstand-error when trying to submit an app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6977357/xcode-gave-strange-newsstand-error-when-trying-to-submit-an-app)

even though I deleted my entire "Icon files (iOS 5)".

How do I solve this to get through with the Validation so I can upload my app with AppLoader?

here is a pic on the info http://screencast.com/t/xMeggabvCF

Comment: Can you post your Info.plist file?  Or at least a portion of it?

Comment: http://screencast.com/t/xMeggabvCF that is my info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the entry in your Info.plist that says "Application presents content in New..." or set it to NO instead of YES.

That entry is explicitly saying that your "Application presents content in Newstand".

Comment: weird I tried to set "Application presents content in Newstand" to NO and i still got the same error, then I tryd to delete "Application presents content in Newstand" and I still got the same error as before..

Comment: Just know that you'll have to rebuild and rearchive your application after making changes in your Info.plist file.  All I can suggest is to do a clean build, and make sure that there really aren't any other Icon Files related to Newsstand in your Info.plist.  I can't tell from your screenshot because that entry is collapsed.

Comment: I pressed product -> archive again and validated the new one and the present issue with newsstand disapread, tho I got an new issue which it says:
"Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key 'CFBundleIconFiles': '144x144'"
I get the exact same error aswell with the resolutions 76x76, 152x152 and 120x120.

I have created Icons with this resoultion and added them to the correct place in "General" but I still encoutner the same error, I remeber getting the same error a while back with other resolutions and I solved it by following a guide which told me to name the icons!

Comment: Ok, post that as a new question along with a screenshot of your Info.plist file.  Make sure to actually show the entries under Icon Files in that screenshot.

Comment: Alright! I did that, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19251091/xcode-error-invalid-image-path-cfbundleiconfiles-144x144-152x152-76x76-and-120 Thx for the help again!