# Xcode error Invalid Image Path - CFBundleIconFiles 144x144,152x152,76x76 and 120x120

Tags: ios, xcode

When I try to validate my app in archive I get an error that tells me
"Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key 'CFBundleIconFiles': '144x144'" I get the exact same error aswell with the resolutions 76x76, 152x152 and 120x120.

I created icons in this resolutions and uploaded them in Xcode but I still get this error...

It looks like this: http://screencast.com/t/hNWHqyBHSoz7
And this is my info.plist: http://screencast.com/t/SL0lSG4xhChU

Comment: Make sure each size is added to the xcode project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure those images are a members of target you are building:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZuVe7.jpg

Otherwise they are not gonna be a part of your IPA file.

Also be aware that names are case sensitive - all files you have problems with are lower "i" and working ones are uppercase.

Comment: My Xcode show the same as that picture, Now by mistake I did something in the project navigator and when I try to Archive I get errors, please look at my comment bellow

Comment: How about case sensitive names - I see some of them are upper "i" some not ?

Comment: that could be it! Tho my friend I made an horrible misstake, I accidently deleted the files and then put them back but that just gave me many errors, do you mind looking into my other thread?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19258571/interface-builder-could-not-open-the-document-mainstoryboard-iphone-storyboard
Xcode is surely making me crazy..

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you actually have images with those names added to your XCode project.  Also, make sure that those images are a part of the Target you are building or else they won't get copied into your application's bundle.