# App update submission error

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

While trying to submit an app update for an existing app, the update is getting uploaded successfully from Xcode onto iTunes Connect, when i try to submit the update for review, i get the following error:

> *Apps enabled for Newsstand must not contain the `UIPrerenderedIcon` key in the CFBundleIcons.UINewsstandIcon dictionary. Ensure that your CFBundleIcons.UINewsstandIcon dictionary contains the CFBundleIconFiles.
>   Newsstand apps must contain the UINewsstandBindingType in the CFBundleIcons.UINewsstandIcon dictionary.*

My app has Newsstand enabled, I have not encountered this error message earlier.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19232906/xcode-keeps-giving-me-newsstand-error-everytime-i-try-validate-my-app-through-ar

Comment: This SO thread helped with a resolution, they have mentioned that the Newsstand Icon dictionary should be removed, for my app the dictionary entry was missing from the plist, adding the dictionary entry resolved the problem:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6977357/xcode-gave-strange-newsstand-error-when-trying-to-submit-an-app